# GL Error: Out of Memory when trying to use glBindVertexArrayOES?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-extensions

I have searched around the web but doesn't find how `glBindVertexArrayOES` has to work exactly.

For now VAO usage leads to `GL Error: Out of Memory`. Can anyone give me advice or maybe share link to documentation with appropriate examples of VAO usage?

**Note:**
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805539/gl-error-out-of-memory-when-trying-to-render-with-vbo#21805736) possibly covers the issue in my usecase.

Comment: Does this link help http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8044 ?

Comment: @Kiran Thank you for the link. It's nice to be the entry point to VAO. But maybe you're informed also about a case how VAO can lead us to `GL Error: Out of Memory`?

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure on that. Possibly experts will help if you post a question with error message as title.